# Cypress cucumber preprocessor custom parameter type with typescript

Tags: typescript, cucumber, cypress

I am using cypress-cucumber-preprocessor with cypress and typescript. Also I noticed there is a possibility to use custom parameter types as shown here:
https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/cypress/support/step_definitions/customParameterTypes.js

But I am getting trouble running it with Typescript.

Interface in typscript is defined as `export function defineParameterType(): void;`
so if I import module, I cannot write a propper definition.

But if I use javascript as shown in expamle, then I always get error

`Uncaught Error: Undefined parameter type {boolean}`

My javascript code looks like this:

```
defineParameterType({
  name: "boolean",
  regexp: /true|false/,
  transformer(s) {
    return s === 'true';
  }
});
```

Is there a way to get it working using Typescript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation around the custom types is a little light (this isn't a criticism of the package authors btw, documentation is hard work).

I was able to make it work by defining my custom types in `support/custom-parameter-types.ts` and then in step files where I wanted to use custom types imported that file using `import '<path-to-your-support-folder>/custom-parameter-types';`

I'm not 100% sure this is exactly the right way to do things, but it does seem to work.

Edit: I should note that while this works, depending on your editor/IDE you might find that steps appear undefined in your feature files.

Comment: This works for me and looks to be the expected approach for now, at least. In their own [example](https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/e7c08048f32f74d4884bc7f582a9deb9405f5457/cypress/support/step_definitions/customParameterTypes.js), the steps using the custom parameters are defined in the same file.